How to get logs for a job in bullmq
I was trying to add logs to my bullMQ jobs which uses the following method
job.log("SOME LOG");

But when retreiving logs you just get the count of the log and no log values.
How do I get job logs?

Finally found a solution in the files here:
const { logs } = await queue.getJobLogs(job.id);

You can get the logs in the queue not on the job directly
